# Show that $X_1^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1}X^T] = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Where $X$ is an $n \times k$ matrix such that $X := [X_1 X_2]$

i.e $X_1$ consists of the first few columns of $X$

Also, note that: 
$X^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1} X^T] = X^T - X^T = 0$

I need this to prove the frisch-waugh-lovell theorem, every proof I can find on the internet just skips over this step.

Comment: Note that if you can write $X_1 = XC$ for some $C$ you are done.

Comment: @ACARCHAU You're a *genius*. I *appreciate* you.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @ACARCHAU I was able to do this, it was really simple once he pointed out the trick. Let me write down the solution for anyone else who stumbles upon this thread:

I want to show that $X_1^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1}X^T] = 0$
as i pointed out in the initial question: 
$X^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1} X^T] = X^T - X^T = 0$

Now $X_1^T$ = XC. C is an nxk' matrix where k' are the number of columns in $X_1^T$. C has a pivot in every row which is equal to the desired columns from $ X^T $. For example:

X= $$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
        a&b&c\\
        d&e&f\\
        g&h&i
    \end{matrix}
   \right] $$

and $X_1$ = $$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
        a&b\\
        d&e\\
        g&h
    \end{matrix}
   \right] $$

then C= $$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        1&0\\
        0&1\\
        0&0
    \end{matrix}
   \right] $$

Now $X_1 = XC$ and $X_1^T = C^TX^T$ and

$X_1^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1}X^T] = C^TX^T[I_n - X({X^T}X)^{-1}X^T]$ = C 0 = 0

all credit to @ACARCHAU